# induction principle in logic

Tags: logic, induction

"every well-formed formula has exactly twice as many parentheses as it does binary logical connective" When I tried to argue this problem, I started with some examples to show exact twice as many parentheses as it does binary logical connectives. I knew I should focus on the induction principle to argue this, but do not know how to make it clear. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Have you ever seen proofs by induction over the complexity (number of symbols in a formula) ?

Comment: No. I will look it up.

Comment: Where does this lead? Why do we want to derive theorems about the text of logical statements using some kind of meta-language? Is it just an exercise in writing proofs by induction?

Answer (score 2):

The best thing to do in problems like these is to use what is called *structural induction*, and that is where the induction follows the recursive definition of the objects in question.

Logic formulas are defined as follows:

1. Every atomic proposition $P$ is a formula.
2. Where $\varphi$ and \psi$ are formulas, the following are formulas as well:

a. $\neg \varphi$

b. $(\varphi \land \psi)$

c. $(\varphi \lor \psi)$

etc.

3. Nothing else is a formula.

So, given this definition, you set up the induction as follows:

Bases case: show that the property in question holds for atomic formulas

Step: Assume that the property in question holds for $\varphi$ and \psi$, and then show it holds for:

a. $\neg \varphi$

b. $(\varphi \land \psi)$

c. $(\varphi \lor \psi)$

etc.

Once you've shown these, you are done, since that means that the property in question holds for all formulas, because by 3. of the definition, every formula must have been created by the recursive process as given by 1. and 2.

Comment: @JDH Of course, thank you! :)